# Why cant RNN learn long term dependencies=?

Tags: rnn

In Colah's blog, he explain this.

> In theory, RNNs are absolutely capable of handling such “long-term
>   dependencies.” A human could carefully pick parameters for them to
>   solve toy problems of this form. Sadly, in practice, RNNs don’t seem
>   to be able to learn them. The problem was explored in depth by
>   Hochreiter (1991) [German] and Bengio, et al. (1994), who found some
>   pretty fundamental reasons why it might be difficult.

In quick explanation what is the `fundamental reasons why it might be difficult`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is no explicit notion of memory (like gates in lstm and gru)**

Gates are a way to optionally let information through, ommiting this functionality we will just be updating weights that will in process fade away hence longer memory is hard to learn.